# How fast is decryption by a YubiKey?

Tags: ssh, performance, gpg, yubikey

Do YubiKeys decrypt GPG or SSH/SFTP data directly within themselves? If so, would that cause a bottleneck? Do YubiKeys have accelerated AES hardware that does most of the heavy lifting of decryption?

Also, YubiKeys aren't needed when encrypting to another person's key, correct?

Comment: Yubikeys do not encrypt data, they supply keys https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/yubikey-one-time-password-authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YubiKey only does public key cryptography, not symmetric cryptography.

In each of those cases, the YubiKey is used to encrypt (or decrypt) a symmetric key, which is then used by a symmetric cipher such as AES. The YubiKey is not involved at all, after this key is made available. Symmetric cryptography is performed by the device (computer, phone, etc).